# downloaded a file unzipped it and its a .15 file

Tags: directory, downloads, tar, zip

i downloaded a file it was a .xz file so i unzipped it and the file name was Debian_for_stora3.18 it was not a folder it needs to be is there a way to convert it into a folder

Comment: Do you have a link to this download?

Comment: [link](http://hajduk.one.pl/Netgear%20Stora%20MS2000%20MS2110%20kernel%204.2.5/Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.xz)

Comment: thats the link of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the filetype of the downloaded file with `file` utility.

It reports:

> ```
> $ file Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.xz 
> Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.xz: gzip compressed data, last modified: Fri Nov  6 13:45:21 2015, from Unix
> ```

So the file is really *gzip compressed* and you need to rename it to *.gz* and extract with `gunzip`:

```
mv Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.xz Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.gz
gunzip Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5.gz
```

As the result you will get unpacked ext4 file:

```
$ file Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5
Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data, UUID=33dbfa63-f902-4501-b0bc-da04484525b2 (extents) (large files) (huge files)
```

I can even mount it:

> ```
> $ sudo mount -o loop Debian_Jessie_for_Netgear_Stora_MS2000_MS2110+Kernel-4.2.5 /mnt/
> $ head -n1 /mnt/etc/os-release 
> PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
> ```

Comment: when i mount it it on mac osx says mount: You must specify a filesystem type with -t.

Comment: I ran this mount command on my Ubuntu 16.04 LTS system. Here it was mounted without `-t`. But you can try to pass `-t ext4` manually. Check the options of your `mount` command.